# D: how to extract data from archive?

Tags: d, archive

I have very simple code that should extract data from archive:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.file;
import std.algorithm;
import std.zip;

void main()
{
    string ar = `D:\ftp\s2-imfset_2015\IFPET-150101.zip`;
    auto zip = new ZipArchive(ar.read);
    foreach(ArchiveMember am; zip.directory)
    {
        writeln(am.expandedData);
    }
}
```

(thanks for explaining about `each` and map `difference`). But when I run it it's print `[]` on console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `zip.expand(am)` before the expanded data is available.
You can also get the name and size of an archive member before expanding it.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.file;
import std.algorithm;
import std.zip;

void main()
{
    string ar = `D:\ftp\s2-imfset_2015\IFPET-150101.zip`;
    auto zip = new ZipArchive(ar.read);
    foreach(name, am; zip.directory)
    {
        if(!am.expandedSize) continue; // ignore empty files
        zip.expand(am);
        writeln(am.expandedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simply, `writeln(zip.expand(am))`.

Comment: I made a pull to add this example to the documentation. https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/3131