# D: how to add file to zip archive?

Tags: zip, d, archive

I think it's better to split it's in two separate questions, to help newcomers to find answer.

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373470/d-how-to-extract-data-from-archive) was about extracting data from zip archive. But now I need any example that show how to add data to zip archive.

There is 2 situation.
1. stand alone file
2. test string like: `string foo = "qwerty";` 
How send it's to zip?

in the docx of `std.zip` I found method `addMember(ArchiveMember de);`, but I do not understand how to pass data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the new docs don't show usage for this module. I read the source and sorted out that this is the way to do it:

```
import std.file: write;
import std.string: representation;
import std.zip: ArchiveMember, ZipArchive;

void main()
{
    char[] contents = "This is my test data.\n".dup;

    // Create the archive.
    auto zip = new ZipArchive();

    // Create the archive entry
    ArchiveMember ae = new ArchiveMember();
    ae.name = "test.txt";
    ae.expandedData(contents.representation);

    // Add to the entry to the archive.
    zip.addMember(ae);

    // Build the archive. 
    void[] compressed_data = zip.build();

    // Write the archive data to a file.
    write("test.zip", compressed_data);
}
```

And it works:

```
$ ./addzip
$ unzip test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: test.txt                
$ cat test.txt
This is my test data.
```

The next version of Phobos will have examples in the documentation showing how to read and write zip files.